# Do keyboards have a selftest result indicated by LEDs?

Tags: keyboard, led

After yesterday's Windows 10 update and reboot, BIOS hung before booting.
As it turned out it's something with the keyboard.
Still I'm unsure whether it's the keyboard (only 30 years old ;-)) or the PS/2 on-board connector.
Hard to believe that a Windows update killed my hardware, but anyway:

Noticing that all three keyboard LEDs were flashing three times after a reset, I wonder whether the keyboard wanted to tell me something:
Are there any common LED-indicated (pattern of flashing) keyboard self-test results?

Comment: As a matter of fact, it seemed to be a software problem (like the keyboard being crashed): After a lengthy power-off phase the keyboard worked again. Before I had interrupted power too, but obviously not long enough to discharge all capacitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody did answer, here is what I found ([The PS/2 Keyboard Interface](http://www.Computer-Engineering.org)):

At *power-on* or *software reset* ("Reset" command) the keyboard performs a *diagnostic self-test* referred to as **BAT** (*Basic Assurance Test*).
When entering BAT, the keyboard enables its three LED indicators, and turns them off when BAT has completed (so they flash once for about 0.5s).

The host may send a command to the keyboard, e.g.:

- 0xFF (Reset) - Keyboard responds with "ack" (0xFA), then enters "Reset" mode (See above).

So observing the three LEDs flash three times seemed to indicate that the host sent a *reset* to the keyboard three times (and then probably gave up for an unknown reason).

I also found [M17x and M15x LED Error Codes LED Error Codes](https://www.techinferno.com/index.php?/forums/topic/1019-alienware-m15x-m17x-led-error-codes/) that indicates that the system BIOS may use the keyboard LEDs to signal a system error.